# Issues with retrieving Firebase data into a textbox in html page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
// Calls the onClick command from the Populate Button
function myFunctionPopulate() {

// Creates a new Firebase reference linking this JS to the Firebase database
var ref = new Firebase("https://project01-d018e.firebaseio.com/Numbers");

// Creates a snapshot of the data from the desired Firebase database and adds it to 'value' 
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

// Adds a console log of the data recived from Firebase
console.log(snapshot.val());

// Creates a variable called data to which the snapshot is saved
var data = snapshot.val();

for (var key in data) {
  
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    // Takes the id of the textbox and adds a value of (data[key]) where data = snapshot.val() which is the snapshot of the data
    document.getElementById('id1').value=(data[key]);

    // Adds a console log message to confirm the textbox has been populated
    console.log('Value Added');
    };
    // End of if
  }
  // End of for
});
// End of ref.on
}
// End of function
```

```html
<div id="button">
  <button id="RButton" value="submit" onclick="myFunctionPopulate()">Populate</button>
</div>

<div id="button2">
  <button id="RButton" value="submit" onclick="myFunctionClear()">Clear</button>
</div>

<div id="textBox">
  <form>
  From Firebase<br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="id1"></textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

I have recently started using Google Firebase as a storage solution for storing data. So far so good - I'm liking it!

However, I am trying to display data from Firebase database into my HTML website which consists of 2 buttons and a textarea. 1 button for populating the text area the other for clearing. Very simple stuff for the moment.

Currently, when I hit the populate button the onClick function performs this piece of JS:

[JS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJVtH.png)

****Project name has been changed to  just for sake of example****

Numbers - Which this JS is referencing to - Looks like this in the Firebase console:

[Firebase Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwgo6.png)

When I hit the populate button the textarea is populated within the HTML, however, only the last piece of data from Numbers is displayed and not the whole list.

I wish to show all the data into this text area if possible.

If anyone can shed any light onto this I would be really grateful - I'm unsure whether the issue is something to do with the 'Key' part of the JS as i'm unsure what this actually does - It is a snippit from a GitHub piece of work which I have adjusted to fit my work.

I have now attached the JS and HTML although it wont work because it does not contain the firebase script tags or firebase initialisation tag but hopefully having the text makes it clearer

Thank you in advance,
G

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of text, post the actual text. For the JSON you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where I can find the Export JSON.. does it make a difference that my app isnt hosted?

Comment: I have updated the post - Hopefully the changes may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're only seeing the last piece of data is that you're replacing the contents of the textarea on every iteration of your for loop instead of appending it. Run the below code snippet for an example. In `textarea` `id1` I'm doing what you are doing, and in `textarea` `id2` I'm appending to the current value instead of replacing it.

```js
var data = ['first','second','third'];

for (var key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {
 document.getElementById('id1').value = data[key]
  document.getElementById('id2').value += data[key]
}
```

```html
<textarea id="id1"></textarea>
<textarea id="id2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Jeff you're a legend! Such a simple fix! Wish I could up-vote but my rep isn't high enough.. but none the less thank you!